# How do I use VBA in Excel to save Powerpoint as PDF using add-in PDFMaker?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, powerpoint

I am updating a Powerpoint presentation with charts etc. from Excel using VBA in Excel. What I would like to do is to save that presentation as PDF using the PDFMaker add-in in Powerpoint, from the VBA code. The reason I want to use the add-in is that the quality of the PDF comes out better than at regular "Save As PDF".

I am using Office 2010 and Adobe Acrobat XI Standard, on Windows 7.

My code works fine until I reach the stage where I invoke the CreatePDFEx method. Then I get the error:

"""
Run-time error '-2147023170'

Automation error
The remote procedure call failed.
"""

This is part of the code I use, having specified "pdfname" earlier in the code:

```
Dim pmkr As AdobePDFMakerForOffice.PDFMaker
Dim stng As AdobePDFMakerForOffice.ISettings
Dim pdfname As String
Dim a As Object

Set pmkr = Nothing ' locate PDFMaker object
For Each a In pptApp.COMAddIns
    If InStr(UCase(a.Description), "PDFMAKER") > 0 Then
    Set pmkr = a.Object
    Exit For
    End If
Next

If pmkr Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot Find PDFMaker add-in", vbOKOnly, ""
    Exit Sub
End If

If Dir(pdfname) <> "" Then Kill pdfname

pmkr.GetCurrentConversionSettings stng
stng.AddTags = True
stng.AddLinks = True
stng.AddBookmarks = True
stng.FitToOnePage = True
stng.ConvertAllPages = True
stng.OutputPDFFileName = pdfname
stng.PromptForPDFFilename = False
stng.ShouldShowProgressDialog = True
stng.ViewPDFFile = False

pmkr.CreatePDFEx stng, 0 ' perform conversion

If Dir(pdfname) = "" Then ' see if conversion failed
    MsgBox "Could not create " & pdfname, vbOKOnly, "Conversion failed"
End If

Set pmkr = Nothing
Set stng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and what I can do about it?